# Vertical divider between columns in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny application in which I would like to have a vertical divider (vertical line) between some UI elements that are all in the same fluidRow().  In the very trivial example (below), I would like to see this:

[image]

I've found a few suggestions of how to do it with CSS, but I can't find a way to integrate those into my Shiny app.  (I don't know CSS, obviously.)  The actual app is currently using shiny, shinydashboard, and shinydashboardplus, if that helps.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Divider example"),

    mainPanel(
        fluidRow(
            column(12, 
                plotOutput("distPlot")
            )
        ),
        fluidRow(
            column(6,
                   sliderInput(inputId = 'sldNumPts', min = 10, max = 1000,
                               value = 50, label = 'Number of Points')
            ),
            column(6,
                   sliderInput(inputId = 'sldBreaks', min = 10, max = 50,
                               value = 10, label = 'Number of Breaks'),
                   radioButtons(inputId = 'rdoColor', label = 'Color', 
                                choices = c('red', 'green', 'blue'), 
                                inline = TRUE)
            )
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        hist(rnorm(input$sldNumPts), breaks = input$sldBreaks, 
             col = input$rdoColor, border = 'white')
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add CSS through the `style` argument. In this case, you can add a border in `column` within your `ui`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Divider example"),
  
  mainPanel(
    fluidRow(
      column(12, 
             plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(6,
             sliderInput(inputId = 'sldNumPts', min = 10, max = 1000,
                         value = 50, label = 'Number of Points')
      ),
      column(6,
             sliderInput(inputId = 'sldBreaks', min = 10, max = 50,
                         value = 10, label = 'Number of Breaks'),
             radioButtons(inputId = 'rdoColor', label = 'Color', 
                          choices = c('red', 'green', 'blue'), 
                          inline = TRUE),
             style = 'border-left: 1px solid'
      )
    )
  )
)
```

For more information on integrating CSS into your `shiny` app, refer to [this resource](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html).